# Magento: change to Product Name or Description not displayed on frontend

Tags: magento

When I make a change to the Product Name or Description that change is not displayed on the frontend. It looks fine from the admin side but does not show the change on the frontend.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry, forgot to post resolution.

Flushing Cache and indexing did not work. Here is what did:

1. Edit product
2. Change "Store View" upper left
3. Make sure next to the Description field, the following checkbox was checked:

   [ ] Use Default Value

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be a multi-store feature.
Somehow the "Use Default Value" is unchecked for name, description and short-description.
Which means that any change to the default won't be shown in a storeview.

I'll bet there is a way the make sure these are checked-by-default but I couldn't find it.

My current solution is to change the "attributes" name, description and short-description and set them to "global"

This will keep all these setting equal for all stores

If anyone finds a better fix please let me know

Comment: Flushing magento cache is still needed but you'll get a notice this time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried flushing magento cache?

Comment: Basically have to reindex/flush cache on every change.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-indexing data and flushing cache from **Magento Admin**.

> **System -> Index Management**
>
> **System -> Cache Management**